# How can I prevent scrolling to change menu in InkScape?

Tags: scrolling, inkscape

I suppose the title says it all. I hate that when I scroll through panel, when my pointer is above a menu and I tried to scroll down, it changes the menu instead of scrolling down the panel instead.

Some cases, I was confused on why my InkScape behaves oddly, then I realized some values changed because I had it changed when I tried to scroll down the menu.

**How can I prevent scrolling to change menu in InkScape?** In ideal case scenario, I want scrolling to only scroll down/up a panel, without changing anything.

Comment: Do you mean scrolling with Ctrl-arrows? Pressing ESC should "return to canvas", but doesn't work well if cursor is e.g. on a numeric field in a dialog.

Comment: No. What I meant is when you scroll through panel, for example you want to scroll down to Align and Distribute panel, but instead you scrolled on a drop down menu.